Changing what the default bookmark title is for users on my website
Currently I am doing some work on someone's website and had a unique request I haven't heard before.  They noticed that when they bookmarked/favorited their website on their browser, the title it defaults to is not what they wanted.
Bookmark location
To be more specific, I am talking about the list of site titles that appear when you press on this all bookmarks button.  Another wrinkle in this as well is that it is built with MediaWiki (not done by me).  I know that you can change the bookmark title as you make it as a user, but he wants me to change what it appears as by default, before the user changes it.
I've attempted to do research this on my own but have been having trouble because of a lack of knowledge of the terminology I should be using.
Another example of what I'm talking about

"the title it defaults to is not what they wanted" - Can you elaborate on "defaults" and "what they wanted"? To the best of my knowledge, bookmarks still always use the page's title (as determined at the time of performing the bookmarking action if JS is manipulating it), and once something is bookmarked, the browser doesn't query the site to determine if it should be updated. The "All Bookmarks" is just a weird/annoying button that appears if you have something in "Other bookmarks". Can this just be solved by having nice page titles?

The bookmark name defaults to whatever is in the <title> element. So change that.

Apologies for not being clear enough.  I think an easier explanation would be that I am trying to change the title that appears for the "tab box" when the website is open.  I've attached another photo to help explain what I'm talking about, using an example of the stack overflow main page.  Where in the backend of the website would this be located?

The tab heading is the 

@Barmar Do you have any idea how the title tag could be changed with a website built using MediaWiki?

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_title
